# How can I declare a variable of @types/waterline in typescript def file in vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

I am trying to declare a variable of type. I can see intelisense auto completion after that but typescript throws error saying `Cannot find name 'User'.ts(2304)`
here is the global.d.ts file -

```
import { Model } from "@types/waterline";
declare var User: Model
```

Intelisense works fine but I see the error saying `Cannot find name 'User'.ts(2304)`. Also my project does not use typescript. I just want static type checking from typescript.

Comment: How can you have static type checking from TypeScript without using TypeScript in your project? I am not sure how that can be a working situation.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the error `Cannot find name 'User'.ts(2304)`?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin You can typescript checking for js project by specifying jsconfig.json instead of tsconfig.json [more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html). And I see the error where ever I use User variable. It is a global variable associated with waterline model.